# Nueva Pagina en jqgrid

Tags: jquery, ms-access, jqgrid

Buenos dias un gusto en saludarlos, estoy usando Jqgrid para simular un grid de Access, lo cargo via ajax y todo bien de momento, mi problema surge es cuando necesito implementar el boton de nueva pagina que esta en access lo muestro en la siguiente imagen,[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Es decir actualmente tengo los botones de navegacion que tiene el Jqgrid,
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
 y se mueve entre registros via ajax, pero no tengo idea de como implementar el boton de nuevo registro.

Gracias de Antemano por su ayuda

Answer (score 0):

Como algo parecido a eso en jqgrid no lo logre encontrar agregue un boton, al precionar genero un registro nuevo y solicito la ultima pagina y en el response del ajax hago un trigger hacia la ultima pagina nueva generada.

ejemplo:

```
 jQuery("#jqgrid").jqGrid('navButtonAdd',"#pjqgrid",
                { caption:"", 
                buttonicon:"ui-icon-newwin", 
                onClickButton:new_presupuesto, 
                position: "last", 
                title:"Nuevo Presupuesto", 
                cursor: "pointer"});
    $('.navtable .ui-pg-button').tooltip({
        container : 'body'
    });


function new_presupuesto(){

    $.post("tu url aqui",{
        op:14
    },function(data){
        var resp = eval(data);
        if(resp){
            var s_presupuesto=  parseInt($("#sp_1_pjqgrid").text())+1;
            var grid = $("#jqgrid");
            grid.setGridParam({
                page: s_presupuesto
            });
            grid.trigger("reloadGrid");
        }
        else{
            console.log("respuesta "+data);
        }
    });

}
```